# Python : How to convert data from excel in table form into json

Tags: python, json, dictionary, recursion, nested

[image]

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15Lbl8N4ZDWQZeAexVIL_SnLGYUqnfC4G) is the table created in excel  and is to be converted into json data. Like this :

```
    { "maintitle": {"idno": "10",
           "subheading": [ {  "prop": "val1",
                             "prop2": "val12",
                            "attrib": {"type": "well"},
                             "attri": {"pos": "[]"}},
                           {  "type": "ok",
                            "prop11": {"subprop1": "10",
                                       "subprop2": "abc",
                                       "subprop3": "0.202",
                                       "subprop4": "moreval1"},
                          "moreprop": {  "type": "dot",
                                     "diffdata": ["3030.22","3903.22"]}
                             }
                           ]
                }
  }
```

Here : Column names ending with [x] are read as python list having elements below it present at index x.
Column names without [x] are read as python dictionary.

Below is the code but it does not give the desired result:

```
from mergedeep import merge, Strategy
# data from excel is read & saved in variable columnlist
columnlist=[['maintitle', 'idno'],
 ['maintitle', 'subheading[0]', 'prop'],
 ['maintitle', 'subheading[0]', 'prop2'],
 ['maintitle', 'subheading[0]', 'attrib', 'type'],
 ['maintitle', 'subheading[0]', 'attri', 'pos'],
 ['maintitle', 'subheading[1]', 'type'],
 ['maintitle', 'subheading[1]', 'prop11', 'subprop1'],
 ['maintitle', 'subheading[1]', 'prop11', 'subprop2'],
 ['maintitle', 'subheading[1]', 'prop11', 'subprop3'],
 ['maintitle', 'subheading[1]', 'prop11', 'subprop4'],
 ['maintitle', 'subheading[1]', 'moreprop', 'type'],
 ['maintitle', 'subheading[1]', 'moreprop', 'diffdata[0]'],
 ['maintitle', 'subheading[1]', 'moreprop', 'diffdata[1]']]

jsondict={}
for col in columnlist:
    tmpdict=''
    for key in reversed(col):
        if '[' in key:
            tmpdict = {key: [tmpdict]} 
        else:
            tmpdict = {key: tmpdict}
    merge(jsondict,tmpdict, strategy=Strategy.ADDITIVE)

print(jsondict)
```

I think this can be achieved with recursion. How can it be done using python ?

Comment: Can you send your excel table?

Comment: I have shared the link now. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15Lbl8N4ZDWQZeAexVIL_SnLGYUqnfC4G